# Where are the coupon codes stored?

Tags: wordpress, jigoshop

For the Jigoshop Wordpress Plugin, where in the DB are the coupon codes stored?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still requiring an answer. The coupon codes are stored as a custom post type in the `wp_posts` table. The custom post type they use is `shop-coupon`.

Comment: I found that this was the case for WooCommerce also.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from [DB TABLE NAME] where post_type='shop_coupon'

Comment: ...and what is the table name?

Comment: The table name depends on your config. If you are using default it should be "wpposts"